# build SIP server similar iptel.org by kamailio

Tags: sip, sip-server, kamailio, openser

I want build SIP server like iptel.org. I use this tutorial (http://kb.asipto.com/kamailio:skype-like-service-in-less-than-one-hour) to install Kamailio SIP Server.
But I have some problems.

- Server does not work with UDP.(while I configured kamailito to listen
  to udp)
- Clients only work with proxy.(proxy must config by client.I don't
  want use proxy like iptel)
- I used Jitsi as client,It's sign in but could not call,while EyeBeam
  can call

how can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That config enables Kamailio to listen on UDP. Maybe the problem is transmission over UDP from client to server which might be blocked by carrier firewalls (many started to block VoIP) or some ALG on home router.

You should look at the network traffic on the server to see if the SIP packets arrive there - you can use ngrep like:

```
ngrep -d any -qt -W byline port 5060
```

Also, there is no requirement for an intermediate proxy, the config is for direct client-server communication.

For troubleshooting, besides looking at SIP network traffic, you can set debug=3 in kamailio.cfg, restart kamailio and watch the messages in the syslog file. There should be hints regarding what happens during processing and you should get a clue regarding EyeBeam vs Jitsi differences.

The tutorial you linked in your question was tested with Jitsi and works with it. Might be some misconfiguration of Jitsi that creates problems.